# CMake, ensure targets and files are up to date when doing a component-specific install

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

When I build the the "install" target on the generated build system, e.g. `ninja install`, ninja builds all the targets that are to be installed, before actually installing them.

But there are no component-specific `install` targets created, such as `install-<component name>`, when using the `COMPONENT <component-name>` option in one or more `install(...)` command. So you have to use either

```
cmake -DCOMPONENT=Gui -P cmake_install.cmake
```

or

```
cmake --install . --component Gui
```

But these forms do not bother checking whether the targets that are installed are up to date. How can I ensure that for a component-specific install?

Comment: Just run `ninja`, so all files will be ready for installation. There is no component-specific alternative for that purpose.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but the whole point of the component-specific installation was to not build everything for us, but only what the component needs. Hopefully this is possible somehow, otherwise this is a big drawback of cmake install support. Some people may forget to call ninja before the `cmake --install . --component Gui` cmd line, and may then end up with old binaries. IMO bad.

Comment: "the whole point of the component-specific installation was to not build everything for us, but only what the component needs." - No, this is not a point of component-specific installation in CMake. The point is to just categorize installed files, so files corresponding to different components could be packed into e.g. different archives. This is how CPack works. `install()` command in CMake doesn't adjust dependencies at all. It just assumes that all needed files will be ready after building "all" (default) target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hmm I think a configuration option works then, to add or not add targets and install commands based on whether a configuration option was set. Then one keeps doing `ninja install` and depending on the configuration option, more or less is installed.

Comment: Yes, if you want to just limit what is building during `ninja`, then you could add configuration options to the project. Or you may create a custom target, which depends only on needed targets, and explicitly build that custom target.

Comment: I thoughjt about custom targets, but the install step will still be separate and not in anyway be bound to my custom target. I think I will go with configuration options. Here we have our wrapper functions around `add_executable` that looks like `add_our_exe(NAME bar DEPENDS our-foo LICENSE bar SOURCES ...)` and I will just add a `WITH_OPTION <optionname>` to it. If given, the module must explicitly requested by `-DWITH_<optionname>=ON`. Thanks a lot!